# SharePoint Designer Else If Function Review

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I need assistance with my Else If function. For some reason, when I select the option "No" on the task that comes through, nothing happens. It doesn't copy the document at all. Please help!

[image]

Comment: Did you try to use the "Log to History List" action after you create the collect5 variable so you can check its actual value?

Comment: the above comment is very good one. It looks all fine. Please add some log to history list to check states of all the variables you use. Also check ULS logs for any errors after the flow finishes to check for any information there.

Comment: I really and truly appreciate you guys responding to assist me with this task. Getting responses on here is fairly difficult. I added "Then Log this message to the workflow history list" however, I don't know what I should be inputting into the "this message" option. Any suggestions